# Java function to convert CIDR to regex

Tags: java, oracle, networking

I have an oracle database that has a bunch of IP addresses as strings (varchar2). I would like to be able to find ones that are contained within a given CIDR block. Since it's not some native "ip" type, I can't use any sort of native IP search mechanism. I was thinking it's possible to generate a regex off of a cidr (ex: "10.1.0.0/10") that would find the right values.

Anyone have a function or know of a library in java that can do this? Or any alternate solution?

Oracle 12.1.0.2

Comment: yes, a regex that can match IPs in a given cidr block. I have an inet_aton function in oracle that I can use to solve it but the issue there is that it has to run on every record to convert and then compare. So it's really slow when there's a lot of records.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that doesn't answer this question. That is about validating that string /is/ in valid CIDR format. I am asking to find address inside that netblock.

Comment: So - the inputs are a table of IP addresses and a bind variable that represents a CIDR block? And you need a query that will select just the IP addresses in the block? If so, why "regexp"? You say you have some function that does something or other; perhaps whatever you have is not optimal. Ideally you would store IP addresses in NUMBER data type (either instead of or alongside the string representation - perhaps as a calculated column) and use `BITAND` for comparison. Interested? I think I can write the code for this. What is your Oracle version?

Comment: @mathguy yes, if we store the ip as either bits or an integer representation then this is easy. But we have it as a string now. I would like to query against the data we have. If it's not possible then i'll have to go change it and precalculate those values. I just figured there would be an easy way to directly use the data we already have.

Comment: What I meant is, even if you have strings as inputs, it's easy to change that to integers and use integer manipulations to solve your problem. That should be significantly faster than what you can do with regular expressions. I will put something together and write an Answer. But, you still didn't tell us your Oracle version. Please add it at the bottom of your post. It's important.

Comment: @mathguy like I said in my post, I have an "inet_aton" function that can convert the string to an integer and then the compare is fast. The problem is that it has to run the function on every record to know be able to do the compare. I assumed the regex engine would be able to at least optimize some of the work away.

Comment: Where do you have this function? It is not an Oracle SQL or a PL/SQL function. I see that a function by that name exists in various other languages. When you say "can convert the string to an integer" - **where** does that take place? If you need to go between a Java application and the Oracle table, of course it will be very slow. What I mean is a PL/SQL function that works directly on the table. Anyway - I will post an answer, if you care to, you can test it on your data and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The OP (Original Poster) mentions a function "inet_aton" that can convert from the string representation of an IPv4 address to its corresponding integer value. Alas, there is no such function in Oracle SQL and/or in PL/SQL.

In the answer below I show the (trivial!) way in which such a function can be written in PL/SQL. Then I demonstrate how it can be used to solve the OP's problem.

**Note** The OP mentions "regular expressions" as a possible approach to solving the same problem. I doubt that anything along those lines would be anywhere near as efficient as what I propose below. If the blocks are classful (meaning, if the suffix is a multiple of 8), then indeed, it's very easy to write a `regexp_like` condition (we need only match the first one, two, or three "parts" of the four-part IP address). For **classless** blocks, however, the problem becomes much more complicated. **End note**

**EDIT** For what it's worth, I just tried the conversion function on a table with 1.6 million IP addresses. It converted them all to numeric format in 0.3 seconds. **END EDIT**

In the code I create the function as a stand-alone object (a function). If preferred, the function can be defined in a WITH clause in the same query that uses it. That may result in slightly better performance. (One can also use the formula from the function body **directly** in a `select` query, so there are no function calls anywhere, but the performance gain will likely be minimal.)

If performance is important, the OP can add a function-based index to the table that stores the IP addresses; then, for relatively small CIDR blocks, the query should be very fast as long as the filter is sufficiently selective.

Here is one implementation of a function to convert an IPv4 address from the four-part string format to an integer:

```
create or replace function ip_str_to_num (s varchar2) return number
  deterministic
as
  pragma udf;
begin
  return 
  ((to_number(substr(s,1,instr(s,'.',1,1)-1))*256+ 
    to_number(substr(s,instr(s,'.',1,1)+1,instr(s,'.',1,2)-instr(s,'.',1,1)-1))
   )*256+
   to_number(substr(s,instr(s,'.',1,2)+1,instr(s,'.',1,3)-instr(s,'.',1,2)-1))
  )*256+to_number(substr(s,instr(s,'.',1,3)+1));
end;
/
```

Note in particular `pragma udf` - available only since Oracle 12.1; this makes the function work faster, as long as it is only used in SQL context.

Then here is an example of how this function can be used. I create a very small table of "available addresses". Then I show a query where I hard-code a CIDR block (this should be changed to a bind variable, in general); I show how we can use the conversion function to generate the min and max addresses in the block, in numeric format, and then I join to the table of addresses to find just those addresses that belong to the block.

Test data:

```
create table ip_address_list(ip_address varchar2(19));

insert into ip_address_list
  select '123.33.2.234' from dual union all
  select '230.0.0.1'    from dual union all
  select '43.233.83.2'  from dual union all
  select '128.233.2.8'  from dual union all
  select '72.120.0.1'   from dual union all
  select '128.232.1.64' from dual
;

commit;
```

Query and result:

```
with
  inputs(cidr_block) as (
    select '128.224.0.0/10' from dual
  )
, prep(min_addr, suffix) as (
    select ip_str_to_num(substr(cidr_block, 1, instr(cidr_block, '/') - 1)), 
           substr(cidr_block, instr(cidr_block, '/') + 1)
    from   inputs
  )
, address_range(min_addr, max_addr) as (
    select min_addr, min_addr + power(2, 32 - suffix) - 1
    from   prep
  )
select ip_address 
from   ip_address_list join address_range 
                       on ip_str_to_num(ip_address) between min_addr and max_addr
order  by ip_str_to_num(ip_address)
;

IP_ADDRESS         
-------------------
128.232.1.64
128.233.2.8
```